# How the c++ thread::join block implemented?

Tags: c++, windows, multithreading, parallel-processing

How does the C++ `std::thread::join` function implement the block mechanism for waiting for the other thread to finish?

If this is a platform dependent question then I am interested in how this is implemented on Windows and whether it use any hardware special feature or not.
I'm asking this to understand does the function use any busy loop or does it uses any sleep function inside and how much latency I should expect that joint thread will add after this thread is actually finished

I know that this is very platform and hardware dependent but I'm more curious about the concepts rather than the actual number

Comment: You can see [here](https://github.com/microsoft/STL/blob/main/stl/src/cthread.cpp#L56) that (as an example) MSVC's standard library implementation uses `WaitForSingleObjectEx` to wait for the thread termination signal. The function is part of Windows's operating system API and will probably be ultimately implemented somewhere through the kernel.

Comment: @user17732522 Thanks sir, That was all I needed. Please post that as an answer if you feel so